# Workflow rule for (After Inser or AfterUpdate) trigger logic

Tags: workflow

Requirement:
Update Account_Customer_Status__c on Account based on Opportunity's StageName (recently created Opportunity's StageName should be considered if multiple Opportunies exist). 
It should happen when an Oppotunity is created or edited.
Update should not happen if Account_Customer_Status__c is 'Closed (Duplicate)' or 'Closed (Settled)'  or Closed (Declined).

This is what I tried:
Workflow Rule on Opportunity:
AND(
 ISCHANGED( StageName ),
NOT(Account.Account_Customer_Status__c ="Closed (Duplicate)"),
NOT(Account.Account_Customer_Status__c ="Closed (Settled)"),
NOT(Account.Account_Customer_Status__c ="Closed (Declined)"),
NOT(Account.Account_Customer_Status__c ="Closed - Do Not Call")
)

Workflow Action:
Field to Update:    Account: Account Customer Status
Formula Value:  TEXT(StageName)

The problem is it works fine when a Lead is converted and Account, Opportunity are formed the very first time. If I manually try to create new Opportunity for the same converted Account its not working. I know I am missing something, but not able to figure out what it is.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Thank you very much greenstork! I did try ISNEW but it was stupid of me to put this way  ISNEW(Stagename) Where StageName is a picklist and is not supported by ISNEW. But thank you very much for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your logic is that your workflow only fires when the record is changed (edited) and not when it is created new. You will need to add an additional check for ISNEW() to your rule so it will look something like this:

> AND( OR( ISCHANGED( StageName ), ISNEW() ), NOT(Account.Account_Customer_Status__c ="Closed (Duplicate)"), NOT(Account.Account_Customer_Status__c ="Closed (Settled)"),
>   NOT(Account.Account_Customer_Status__c ="Closed (Declined)"),
>   NOT(Account.Account_Customer_Status__c ="Closed - Do Not Call") )